# android - SimpleDateFormat parses data the strange way. Wrong month or/and year

Tags: java, android, date, time, simpledateformat

I have following code snippet:

```
final Date d = format.parse(value);
LOGGER.debug("Compare:\nOriginal: {}, Format: {}, Result: {}", value, format.toPattern(), d);
return d;
```

`value` is a String value from json,

`format` is a java.text.SimpleDateFormat,

`d` is a Date which is parsed from `value`

---

Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes it returns strange dates.

Example from logcat:

```
D/App: 20:14:47.309 com.example.backend.BackendHelper - Compare:
     Original: 2016-09-16 13:45:00.000+0200, Format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ, Result: Fri Jan 01 05:00:00 GMT+07:00 2016
D/App: 20:14:47.309 com.example.backend.BackendHelper - Compare:
     Original: 2016-09-16 13:20:00.000+0200, Format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ, Result: Fri Jan 01 18:20:00 GMT+07:00 2016
D/App: 20:14:47.338 com.example.backend.BackendHelper - Compare:
     Original: 2016-09-16 15:20:00.000+0200, Format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ, Result: Thu Jan 01 05:00:00 GMT+07:00 1970
```

As you can see, it returns incorrect Date (wrong year or/and month or/and hour) for the String values which have absolutely the same format and differ from each other only by hour and minutes.

The question is: **Why**?

Comment: How did you initialize `format`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US),

Comment: Unable to reproduce on plain Java (1.8.0_91 Win64).

Comment: Is it a possibility that you're capturing non-printable characters in the `value` string? I can't see any problems with your code.

Comment: Please make also sure that you don't execute multiple threads on the same format instance at the same time because `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @Frangipanes I don't think so. I get this value from JSON, and I don't see any strange characters even in Postman.

Comment: @MenoHochschild it seems to be a reason, because I use this SimpleDateFormat object as class field in JsonDeserializer<Date> for Gson instance. I'm going to try to fix it and check again.

Comment: @MenoHochschild thank you! You're right! I tried to use org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat instead of SimpleDateFormat and it works awesome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your format pattern is correct. And the locale is not relevant here.

Well, you have also supplied the input in your question so we could investigate if there were any non-printable characters. There aren't (and JSON does not produce such nonsense - very unlikely).

**So what is left as explanation for the observed unpredictable behaviour is lack of thread-safety.** `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe, unfortunately (and has also many other disadvantages). So storing only one instance of `SimpleDateFormat` as static class field is indeed dangerous.

**How to circumvent this limitation of `SimpleDateFormat`?**

- Synchronize the call to parse()-method (causing performance penalty)
- Store the `SimpleDateFormat`-object into a `ThreadLocal` (better)
- Use `FastDateFormat` (performance comparable to ThreadLocale-solution, the prefix "Fast" is nowadays a little bit outdated)
- Use the [ThreetenABP](https://github.com/jakewharton/threetenabp)-library (an Android adaptation around a backport of the new time library package `java.time` incorporated in Java-8), offers an immutable parser), example: `OffsetDateTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))`
- Use [Joda-Time-Android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) (quicker parsing than ThreetenABP, also immutable), example: `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").parseDateTime(input)`
- Or try out my library [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) (IMHO the fastest solution, immutable, too), example: `ChronoFormatter.ofMomentPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT, ZonalOffset.UTC).parse(input)`

Choosing **an immutable formatter/parser** is certainly the best and most modern way to go in a multi-thread-environment. For Android, the libraries Apache Commons and ThreetenABP are more compact than the quicker alternatives Joda-Time or Time4A. You have to make your own evaluation what is more important for you, either size or Performance (or maybe other features you need).